# Flutter error The element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to show two SizedBox in if condition like this code.

```
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              if (randomNumber == 1)[
              
                SizedBox(
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Image.asset('images/test1.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Image.asset('images/test2.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),
            ]
```

At `[` in the line `if (randomNumber == 1)[` it show error like this.

```
The element type 'List<SizedBox>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dart(list_element_type_not_assignable)
```

How to use two sizebox in if condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is that, inside Widget lists, if you want to add more lists of items you need to use the "..." operator. In this case it will be:

```
 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: <Widget>[
      if (randomNumber == 1) ...[
          
        SizedBox(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/test1.jpg'),
          ),
        ),

        SizedBox(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/test2.jpg'),
          ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I used to think that dart was close to c language, Now I have to study dart again.

Comment: "..." is an equivalent of "addAll" and that's why it works. You can also link lists inside lists by doing [ item, item, item ] + [ item, item ] and the + or arrays will merge everything together

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "if() []" to "if() {}". If else statement must use curly braces ({}). Not bracket/array []

Comment: curly braces don't work inside Widget arrays

Answer (score 0):

You are returning list of list. In the if statement there is [] included, remove it and use {} instead.